# Can I use the Kruskal-Wallis test for measures on the same animal before and after a treatment has been applied

Tags: repeated-measures, biostatistics, kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

In my experiment I have 3 treatment groups. Behaviours are scored for each subject (while they are isolated) before and after the treatment is applied.

I thought that the Kruskal-Wallis test could only be used for independent data sets (i.e. not on data from the same subject before and after a treatment). However, I have been advised to use the Kruskall-Wallis test and analyse the data separately for "before" and "after" treatment. I understood previously that the Friedman test was the appropriate test as it is used for repeated measures taken from the same subject (but apparently this will be more complicated).

I have been told to use the Friedman test for a dataset containing behaviours scored each week following treatment (during this observation period the subjects are not isolated but can interact with each other). I think the confusion is arising from whether "independent" means i) non-repeated measures on the same subject or ii) independent of influence from the actions of other subjects. However, I am easily confused with statistics and perhaps I am missing a logical reason why using the K-W test for before and after treatment is ok/better than using the Friedman test...?

I understand that the situation is different due to the treatment being applied but then the behaviours being scored are the same.